# How to change /etc/shadow permissions in yocto recipes?

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I followed something like: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/images/e/e6/Custom_Users_Groups_in_Yocto1.1.pdf
but didn't work.

Expected results:

4.0K -r--r----- 1 root shadow 974 Jan  3  2001 /etc/shadow

I just want to do something like the example below within a recipe.

ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 440 /etc/shadow
ExecStartPre=/bin/chgrp shadow-user /etc/shadow

Does anyone knows which package contains or install the /etc/shadow file?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add more information (step by step) on what you did instead of showing the whole presentation.  Adding your recipe will be really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing a recipe, in your image recipe, you can try by adding:

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "set_new_authorization; "
set_new_authorization () {
    chmod 660 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/shadow
}
```

Comment: Now I am testing your suggestion. I thinks this may work. I will let you know if it works. Thank you thank you for your help :)

Comment: I updated the code, I wrote it with an error. Check it out now